# EditText to mimic TextView?

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-edittext

I am trying to mimic TextView with EditText [as because I have failed to get selected text from TextView]. To do this

I have done this in the xml:

```
    android:selectable="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
```

and this in the code:

```
text.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

This is what I have get:
[image]

How can I get rid of the RED PART?

Comment: You may wish to explain what "get over" means.

Comment: I think if you do `android:textIsSelectable="true"` in `TextView` for API and 11 above, it works. Just curious there another issue with using TextView?

Comment: @CommonsWare edited it! now give me answer :(

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the action mode? The point behind text selection is to allow users to copy the text to the clipboard, and in modern Android devices that is done via the action mode.

Comment: Actually when the button will be placed I want to pop up the selected text and I have failed to do it using TextView so now I am trying to do it with EditText.